# Alternative to "grandfather" in an organizational context

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, business-language, gender-neutral

In organizations sometimes we refer to the manager of a manager as the "**grandfather**".

For example "candidates for senior level positions must go through a *grandfather*'s interview" meaning those candidates must be interviewed by the *hiring manager's manager*.

Is there another way of saying this that is more neutral with respect to gender and isn't awkward "**manager's manager**" or weird "**grand-boss**"?

I've thought "**Überboss**" or "**grand-manager**" or something, but these seem a little too contrived.

Comment: I saw that, but thought that with evolution of diversity and inclusion ideas in recent years, there might be new thinking around this...

Comment: It's only 4 years old...

Comment: There's *second-level report*. (And I just saw from the other question that *second-level manager* is sometimes used—that one was new to me.)